# Is this a viable public key cryptosystem?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Would this, or a variant, work as a public key cryptosystem?

Alice takes a (computable) function p of several variables, let us say $p(x,y)$.  We can think of p as a polynomial and x and y as integers but the variables could easily be other objects such as matrices over the complex numbers.  She chooses  $(a,b)$ in the domain of $p(x,y)$ and posts as her public key  $f(x,y) = p(x,y) – p(a,b)$.  Her private key is the root $(a,b)$ of $f(x,y)$ and for the system to be secure, it must be difficult to find any roots of $f(x,y)$.  (Of course, $a$, $b$ and indeed $p(a,b)$ would be invisible in the publicly stated formula for $f(x,y)$.)

Bob now sends a message $M$ to Alice as follows.  ($M$ can be regarded as a number, or as $diag(M)$ if we use matrices.)  In a similar fashion to Alice, he generates a function $g(x,y) = q(x,y) – q(c,d)$ so that $(c,d)$ is a root of $g(x,y)$.    The function $g(x,y)$ is not made public but Bob transmits over an insecure channel to Alice:
$$M + g(f(x,y) + c, f(x,y) + d);$$

again of course, none of $c$, $d$, $M$ or the expressions for either $g$ or $f$ would be visible in this transmission.  Alice deciphers by putting  $x = a$ and  $y = b$ into the functional expression and recovers                                                                $$M + g(f(a,b) + c, f(a,b) + d) = M + g(0 + c, 0 + d) = M + g(c,d) = M + 0 = M.$$

If Bob wishes, he could multiply the instances of $f(x,y)$ in his transmission by arbitrary functions $r(x,y)$ and $s(x,y)$ and it would make little difference to Alice.

It seems the system will work.  What is more, fresh keys could be generated in an instant so the public key could be regarded as disposable after a single use.

Comment: It seems the transmitted message is a function with constant term (M + z) for some constant z. If we know or can assume that all constants (be they numbers or matrices) are taken from some sufficiently small finite set this might not be very secure. I like the idea of disposable keys, though.

Comment: Maybe [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate site for this question?

Comment: I don't see what is gained here by having everything be a function of two variables; would it not be equivalent, and simpler to write, if you use one variable?

Comment: It seems to me that the hard part is coming up with a function $p$ that is hard to invert, but such that you can publish $f = p(\cdot, \cdot)-p(a,b)$ without revealing $a,b$.  For instance, if $p$ is a cryptographic hash function, the first property is satisfied, but I don't know how you would explain how to compute $f$ without giving away $a,b$.